# Java 8: Reading a file into a String

Tags: java, file, file-io, java-8

I have a json file in the same package of the controller, and I try to read the file and convert it into String

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("CustomerOrganization.json")));
```

But I got an error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: CustomerOrganization.json
```

[image]

Comment: You have to provide the full path, I think. Where (on your file system) is that file stored?

Comment: The path is not relative to the location of your class, but to the location where the program is run. Typically this is the root of the project.

Comment: you could also try giving reative path from root of project like `src/.../controllers/CustomerOrganization.json`

Comment: If you want to find out the path to a file relative to your class, you can use `CustomerControllerIT.class.getResource("CustomerOrganization.json")`

Comment: If you expect it in the same package, you should be using resources, **not** files.

Comment: I recommend adding a encoding parameter to the "new String(...)" call to ensure it reads the file with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using mostly the same methods you used:

```java
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(CustomerControllerIT.class.getResource("CustomerOrganization.json").toURI())));
```

However, if you need it to work from inside a JAR, you will need to do this instead:

```java
InputStream inputStream = CustomerControllerIT.class.getResourceAsStream("CustomerOrganization.json");
// TODO pick one of the solutions from below url
// to read the inputStream into a string:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446009/1356047
```

Comment: True, but this was not requested in the question.

Comment: Nevertheless, if the OP is going to deploy it, it will end up in a Jar. Any solution involving resources should not mix in files, as a project is almost never going to end up deployed as files.

Comment: True, added JAR solution as well.

Comment: The URI detour would even work from a jar, when you create the filesystem first. But it must be emphasized that the `String(byte[])` constructor will use the system’s default encoding which surely isn’t the right choice for a resource embedded in a Java application. The application should be explicit regarding the resource’s encoding.

Comment: What about the encoding?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka are you referring to the answer or to Holger's comment?

Answer (score 4):

You have to give the full path as URI like my below code snippet where the json file is in the same package.

```
try {
        String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:/Test/NTech/src/com/ntech/CustomerOrganization.json")));
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more information you can go through the `public static Path get(URI uri)` method documentation of the `Paths` class from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

Answer (score 2):

Below code snippet should work for you.

```
Path path = Paths.get(CustomerControllerIT.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI());
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String fileContent = new String(fileBytes);
```